# How can I use TPU from colab in tensorflow 1.x about this code of tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

***code of tensorflow 2.x as below:***

import tensorflow as tf

import os

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

resolver =tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://'+
    os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])

tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)

tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)

strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)

a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])

b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

with tf.device('/TPU:0'):

c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print("c device: ", c.device)

print(c)

@tf.function

def matmul_fn(x, y):

z = tf.matmul(x, y)

return z

z = strategy.run(matmul_fn, args=(a, b))

print(z)

***My 1.x code as below:***

%tensorflow_version 1.x

import tensorflow as tf

import os

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

tpu_address = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu_address)

tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)

tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)

strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)

a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])

b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

with tf.device('/TPU:0'):

c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print(c)

def matmul_fn(x, y):

z = tf.matmul(x, y)

return z

with tf.Session() as sess:

with strategy.scope():

z = strategy.experimental_run_v2(matmul_fn, args=(a, b))

print(sess.run(z))

Finally, I am so confused about to use TPU in tensorlfow 1.x on colab.

Comment: I can't read that. Use the ``` code formatting and edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

To create variables on the TPU, you can create them in a `strategy.scope()` context manager. The corrected TensorFlow 2.x code is as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import os

resolver =tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://'+ os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)

with strategy.scope():
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

  @tf.function
  def matmul_fn(x, y):
    z = tf.matmul(x, y)
    return z

  z = strategy.run(matmul_fn, args=(a, b))
  print(z)
```

This runs the `tf.function` on all TPU replicas and gives this result:

```
PerReplica:{
  0: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  1: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  2: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  3: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  4: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  5: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  6: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  7: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
}
```

To evaluate the same function on the TPU in TF 1.x, you'll need to change `strategy.run` to `strategy.experimental_run_v2`, create a `tf.Session` on the TPU, and call `sess.run()` on the list of values returned by `experimental_run_v2`.

The initial setup is the same. Change the `with` block to the following:

```py
with strategy.scope():
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

  @tf.function
  def matmul_fn(x, y):
    z = tf.matmul(x, y)
    return z

  with tf.Session(tpu_address) as sess:
    z = strategy.experimental_run_v2(matmul_fn, args=(a, b))
    print(sess.run(z.values))
```

This gives the following result:

```
(array([[22., 28.],
       [49., 64.]], dtype=float32), array([[22., 28.],
       [49., 64.]], dtype=float32), array([[22., 28.],
       [49., 64.]], dtype=float32), array([[22., 28.],
       [49., 64.]], dtype=float32), array([[22., 28.],
       [49., 64.]], dtype=float32), array([[22., 28.],
       [49., 64.]], dtype=float32), array([[22., 28.],
       [49., 64.]], dtype=float32), array([[22., 28.],
       [49., 64.]], dtype=float32))
```

I hope this answers your question. For more information about running TensorFlow on TPUs, see the [TensorFlow TPU guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu). For more information on using distribution strategies without Keras, see the [guide on distribution strategies with custom training loops](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#using_tfdistributestrategy_with_custom_training_loops)

Comment: I have got your answer, it help my work very very much.But,there is another question on this link about how can code work  from GPU to TPU,would you like to give me some advice about this? I will appreciaten it for you gengerous. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555066/how-to-change-a-code-of-tensorflow-1-15-with-gpu-to-a-code-of-tensorflow-1-15-wi)